# Create a function to return current date and time in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp

I am new to oracle, I have to create a function that returns current date and time.

I am using this to return date;

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM dual;
```

Thanx

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an actual function you could do:

```
create or replace function getSysdate
return date is

  l_sysdate date;

begin

  select sysdate
    into l_sysdate
    from dual;

  return l_sysdate;

end;
/
```

Which you could test in SQLPlus as:

```
TEST>select getSysdate() from dual;

GETSYSDATE
----------
2010-01-04
```

Not sure why you would want this versus just having `sysdate` in your code.  The Oracle date datatype includes the time portion.

Comment: Eek. How about just "return sysdate"?

Comment: True.  I was trying to keep with the theme of what he was doing.  I would just use sysdate instead of any kind of function.

Answer (score 13):

`CURRENT_DATE` returns the date and time of the session.  `SYSDATE` returns the date and time of the database.  These values may be different because  we can change our session's timezone using `ALTER SESSION`.  You probably ought to be using `SYSDATE` because it returns a consistent value, although without knowing your business context it is hard to be certain.

From your question I suspect you don't realise that Oracle date pseudo-columns include a time element.  Try this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24Lmi:ss'
/
select current_date from dual
/
select sysdate from dual
/
```

There is not a lot of point in wrapping one of those pseudo-columns in your own user-defined function.  The one time I seriously considered it was to make it easier to inject times into some automated unit tests.  But I never convinced myself that this facility would justify not using the standard approach.

**edit**

The solution in the accepted answer works but has a lot of unnecessary baggage.  All that additional PL/SQL runs 2-3 times slower than a straight `select sysdate from dual;`.  It is true that these are very small differences in absolute terms - milliseconds, if that.  But in a busy system with lots of calls to `getSysdate()` all those milliseconds could add up to a big chunk of time.  A better solution would be to replace all that code with a plain `return sysdate`;  This is slightly slower than calling `sysdate` directly but only by a little.

Expanding on dpbradley's comment, I have knocked up a function which allows us to substitute a different clocktime from the database, for the purposes of testing.  I am storing my alternate datetime in the CLIENT_INFO namespace in the default context; if I were implementing this in a production system I would build a dedicated user defined context for it.

So here is my take on the `getSysdate()` function...

```
SQL> create or replace function myGetSysdate
  2      ( p_alt_date in varchar2 := null )
  3  return date is
  4  begin
  5      if p_alt_date is null then
  6          return sysdate;
  7      else
  8          return to_date(sys_context('userenv', p_alt_date)
  9                                        , 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
 10      end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Here is how we set the alternate datetime...

```
SQL> exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('01-DEC-2010 12:12:12')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If no parameter is passed it returns `sysdate` (the default and preferred option).

```
SQL> select getsysdate from dual
  2  /

GETSYSDATE
-----------------
05-JAN-2010 16:25

SQL>
```

If we pass a context namespace when we call the function we get the alternate datetime....

```
SQL> select mygetsysdate('CLIENT_INFO') from dual
  2  /

MYGETSYSDATE('CLI
-----------------
01-DEC-2010 12:12

SQL>
```

Comment: If you think your db/application will ever be involved in Real Application Testing playbacks then designing with a wrapper around SYSDATE will help in those environments where you can't change the host clock for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') FROM dual;
```

if you need it in a certain format. More options here:

http://www.psoug.org/reference/date_func.html

Answer (score 0):

The most simple, I suppose:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```